# SwiftUI Core Data Delete related Data of entity

Tags: core-data, swiftui, relationship

im struggling to delete a related entity Data in SwiftUI.
I got 2 entities related.
Bean (main entity)
Shot (related entity)
many to one --> For each bean will be a lot of shots

When I try to build and run I get the error that bean is unresolved.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ShotList: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Bean.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Bean.name, ascending: true)]) var beans: FetchedResults<Bean>
    
    static let taskDateFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(beans, id: \.self) { bean in
                    Section(header: HStack {
                            Text(bean.wrappedName)
                            Text(bean.wrappedRoaster)}) {
                        ForEach(bean.shotArray, id: \.self) { shot in
                            HStack {
                                Text(shot.wrappedTaste)
                                Text(shot.wrappedTexture)
                                Text("\(shot.yield, specifier: "%.0f") g")
                                Text("\(shot.doseAmount, specifier: "%.0f") g")
                                Text("\(shot.bruRatio, specifier: "%.0f")")
                                Text("\(shot.time, specifier: "%.0f") s")
                                Spacer()
                                Text("\(shot.dateOfShot ?? Date(), formatter: ShotList.taskDateFormat)").font(.footnote)                                   
                            }                               
                        }.onDelete(perform: self.deleteShot)
                        .font(.body)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Espresso Shotlist")
        }
    }
    
    func deleteShot(at offset: IndexSet) {
            for offset in offset {
                let shot = bean.shotArray[offset]
                moc.delete(shot)
            }
        try? moc.save()
    }      
}

struct ShotList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ShotList()
    }
}
```

Comment: As there are multiple forms of "bean" in the code, can you please mention the line of code which is giving error.

Comment: it is the line:
let shot = bean.shotArray[offset]

Comment: Try passing bean as an argument to the deleteShot function, such that you call it like this: self.deleteShot(bean: bean, at: indexSet). Adapt the deleteShot function definition accordingly with these parameters and then you should have all necessary information in your function and the code should work.

Comment: Thank you, will try it later.

Comment: One more thing: change the .oneDelete(...) to .onDelete() { indexSet in self.deleteShot(bean: bean, at: indexSet) }. Good luck.

Comment: .onDelete() { IndexSet in self.deleteShot(bean: bean, at: IndexSet) }
 --> now I get the Error for .onDelete...: "Extra argument 'bean' in call"

Comment: As I said, you have to adapt the function definition. Change 
func deleteShot(at offset: IndexSet) {...}  to 
func deleteShot(bean: Bean, at offset: IndexSet) { ... }. Thus you pass that bean (of which you want to delete the shot from) to the delete function.

Comment: Yeahhh, it is working. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

bean is only accessible in the closure: ForEach(beans, id: .self) { bean in

It won't be available in the func deleteShot.